# Contact remove from journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

In marketing cloud will deleting a contact remove them from a journey or will they continue to receive communications?

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if it helped resolve your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

> The deletion process scans all sendable data extensions in an account
>   to remove the specified contact records.

Journey Builder entry source is a sendable DE, so I would say yes, contact's will be removed from the journey.

Reference

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_best_practices.htm&type=5